# Как сделать 2 маленьких блока и 1 большой блок рядом? html

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Заказчик хочет сделать блоки вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это сделать?
**UPD**
Я смог сделать. Скину код если не забуду

Comment: [grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), например

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам должно подойти такое решение:

```
    <div style="height: 300px; display: flex;">
        <div style="flex: 4;">
            <div style="height: 50%; background-color: red;"></div>
            <div style="height: 50%; background-color: green;"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="flex: 8;">
            <div style="height: 100%; background-color: blue;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```